# Como mostrar valor de [input type=date] dentro de modal

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

tengo una tabla que una de sus columnas es modificable.
Este campo de la columna es un [input type=date], y al apretar en Editar, abro un modal en el cual aparece otro [input type=date] que es por el cual voy a modificar.

Mi problema esta en que, al apretar en Editar, quiero que el valor del [input type=date] del MODAL, sea por defecto el que quiero modificar, o sea, el de la columna en la tabla(el que quiero modificar)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Al apretar en EDITAR, abro este modal:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es mi codigo y lo que he intentado:

**Columna tabla que llama a modal**

```
                            <td>
                                @i.FechaVenta.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")
                                <a href="#changeFechaVenta" data-id="@i.idComprobante" data-fecha="@i.FechaVenta.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")" id="FechaVenta" class="ClassEditarFechaVenta" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#changeFechaVenta">Editar</a>

                            </td>
```

**Modal**

```
<div class="modal" tabindex="-1" id="changeFechaVenta" role="dialog">
<div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <h5>Fecha venta</h5>
            <h6>Seleccione una fecha.</h6>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <input type="date" id="fechaVentaACambiar" value="" class="ClassFechaVentaACambiar" />
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" id="EjecutarCambioFechaVenta" onclick="ActualizoFechaVenta()" class="btn btn-primary">Actualizar</button>
            @*<a href="#" class="btn btn-primary btnMonto" target="_blank" id="actualizarMonto" onclick="return ActualizoMonto();"><i class="fas fa-file-pdf"></i>Actualizar monto</a>*@
            <button type="button" id="SalirModal" onclick="CerrarModal()" class="btn btn-primary">Cerrar</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Aca esta la accion de cuando apreto en Editar, que abro el modal, y me quedo con la fecha anterior (en el console.log(FechaVenta) me aparece '01/06/2020' (ESTA BIEN, PERO NO LO PUEDO PONER COMO VALUE EN EL INPUT DEL MODAl)**

```
  $(".ClassEditarFechaVenta").click(function () {
            idFechaVenta = $(this).attr('data-id');
            fechaActual = $(this).attr('data-fecha');
            console.log(fechaActual);
            $("#fechaVentaACambiar").attr("value", fechaActual);
            $("#fechaVentaACambiar").val(fechaActual);


        });
```

**He intentado con .attr o .val y no me sale, si alguien puede ayudarme le agradezco mucho.**

Comment: Usas algún tipo de plugin para el input?

Comment: No, de mi base de datos las fechas llegan como "dd/mm/yyyy", quizas sea por estas razon

Answer (score 1):

Los input de tipo date esperan la fecha en formato YYYY-mm-dd, puedes comprobarlo en la documentación de [https://developer.mozilla.org](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTML/Elemento/input/date)

Por otro lado, para recuperar los valores data, debes hacerlo del siguiente modo: `fechaActual = $(this).data('fecha');`

Comment: FechaActual ya viene con ese formato, en donde creo la fila en html.
En console.log(fechaActual) aparece bien

Comment: ¿Qué formato tiene fechaActual?

Comment: data-fecha="@i.FechaVenta.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")" (esto se encuentra dentro del <td></td>)

Comment: @tato8vio según tu código la fecha tiene formato `dd/MM/YYYY`, o al menos así lo asignas en el código que dejaste en la pregunta `data-fecha="@i.FechaVenta.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")"`

Comment: Gracias por sus respuestas, he probado con el formato que me dices @r4ziel pero tampoco he tenido resultado, alguna otra idea de que podria ser?
puse " data-fecha="@i.FechaVenta.ToString("YYYY-mm-dd")" " y tambien probe en fechaActual.toString("YYYY-mm-dd"), pero sigo igual

Comment: Ofrécenos un fiddle y veamos si podemos ayudarte

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/svza83yu/19/#&togetherjs=PGPB2fSNmT aqui amigo creo que te deja entrar bien